# VBA functions not recognized after add-in installed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a number of VBA functions.  We are developing an add-in to move these out of VBA and into a managed environment.  I opened the spreadsheet while the development add-in was installed and then saved.

Now when I open the spreadsheet without the add-in, all formulas with those functions give me `#NAME?` errors.

If I click in a cell to edit the formula and just hit enter, the function resolves (using the VBA version as the add-in is not installed) correctly.  But I cannot make the entire workbook refresh and use the VBA functions.

1) Is there a way to explicitly tell Excel to use the VBA functions?
2) Is there a way to refresh all the cells without having to manually edit each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stitched this together from a few other posts.  This loops through all sheet and updates all cells' formulas.  Seems to fix the issue, though it takes a while to process.

```
Sub ReapplyFormulas()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

       Set rRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Range("A1:BA500")
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).EnableCalculation = False
       For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
          rCell.Formula = rCell.Formula
       Next rCell
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).EnableCalculation = True
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Calculate
    Next I
End Sub
```